# How to include symfony libraries into external php

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I want access to symfony's libraries of my project into some other php files. e.g. `sfConfig` , `Doctrine_Query` etc. How to do that?

Comment: Trying to understand: You want to use some of the symfony components in PHP, but the full stack? Also, what version of symfony are you trying to use?

Comment: @MrGlass I'm using symfony 1.4. Added a tag for it. And what do you mean by full stack? I just need some include statements.

Comment: the phrase "symfony's libraries of my project" confused me.

Comment: @MrGlass : I need to user classes e.g. `sfConfig`, `Doctrine_Query` etc. I added `require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');` but then it says `Doctrine_Query` not found. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, most of the symfony components cannot be run independently in SF 1.4. Most of the changes in SF2 revolve around being able to use the different components on their own, so if you aren't too far along you might consider switching.

It sounds, though, like you are trying to extend an existing project. There is some good news. Doctrine is its own library, not part of the symfony core, so you should be able to interface with it directly. Accessing the config is more difficult, but if its necessary you can parse in the config file. If you don't want to figure out how to parrse YAML, you can grab the Symfony 2 YAML bundle and run that independently to parse the config.

Comment: no, I need to access Doctrine_Query class. How can I do that?

Comment: Try the doctrine qeury documentation http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/hu/dql-doctrine-query-language

Comment: @prongs Doctrine is its own project, independent of symfony - so you'll have no problem using D1.2 in your project. (Or you might probably want to upgrade to D2) http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm

Comment: Be careful upgrading to Doctrine2, it is very different from 1.2 and you will most likely break your SF 1.4 website.

Comment: I just refactored the code a bit and put some part that required Doctrine libraries in a task. Problem solved. :). @MrGlass : put this in your answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

I can STRONGLY recommend you just one think - Use sf2 components. And here you can find how:

http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1

http://fabien.potencier.org/article/51/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-2

Its because sf2 has totally decoupled architecture
(its components are developped to be reused separately).
Sf1.4 is created to be used as is.

You will very probably spend more time to make sf1.4 parts work decoupled from core than by learning some things about sf2.